# Sending email to a contact group does not send to all group members

Tags: gmail, google-contacts

I have many contact groups and use them to send email to many people at once. When I enter the group name in the recipient section of a draft, though, not all contacts from the group are entered, forcing me to add them manually. Viewing the contact group from Contacts, all of the desired contacts are displayed.

Does anyone know why Gmail does not add the entire contact group when the name is entered, and, if so, how this can be remedied?

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/84086, but unfortunately there's no answer.

Answer (score -2):

I have experienced the same issue and, though I do not know a direct solution, I have found a workaround: In Contacts, select all of the contacts to whom you would like to send the email, then select send mail.

Comment: OP already know about that, so this doesn't answer the question.