# Gmail dropping group members from contact group when sending email

Tags: gmail

I have a group set up in my gmail contacts with 24 people in it. When I type the name of the group into a new email, only 19 of them are added to the "To" list. I email the group once a week and this just started about a week ago. I've tried restarting all my google-related pages, logging out and logging back in, and deleting them from the group and re-adding them.

What could be going on?

Comment: As stated in the original question, the list worked fine until recently. The five people who were dropped used to get the emails just fine- its certainly not that the "contacts don't have email addresses".

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Have you reported it to Google?

Comment: I contacted Google Support about this. They said: we are aware of this issue and our product engineers are working hard to have that fixed. We do apologize for any inconvenience it may have caused.

Answer (score 1):

Per [a comment from Frank H.](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/84086/gmail-dropping-group-members-from-contact-group?rq=1#comment71573_84086)

> I contacted Google Support about this. They said: we are aware of this issue and our product engineers are working hard to have that fixed. We do apologize for any inconvenience it may have caused.

So it would seem that this is a bug. I expect it's been resolved by now.